# how to implement selective property-visibility in c#?

Tags: c#

Can we make a property of a class visible to public , but can only be modified by some specific classes?

for example,

```
// this is the property holder
public class Child
{
    public bool IsBeaten { get; set;}
}

// this is the modifier which can set the property of Child instance
public class Father
{
    public void BeatChild(Child c)
    {
        c.IsBeaten = true;  // should be no exception
    }
}

// this is the observer which can get the property but cannot set.
public class Cat
{
    // I want this method always return false.
    public bool TryBeatChild(Child c)
    {
        try
        {
            c.IsBeaten = true;
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // shoud be ok
    public void WatchChild(Child c)
    {
        if( c.IsBeaten )
        {
            this.Laugh();
        }
    }

    private void Laugh(){}
}
```

**Child** is a data class,
**Parent** is a class that can modify data,
**Cat** is a class that can only read data.

Is there any way to implement such access control using Property in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than exposing the inner state of the Child class you could provide a method instead:

```
class Child {
  public bool IsBeaten { get; private set; }

  public void Beat(Father beater) {
    IsBeaten = true;
  }
}

class Father {
  public void BeatChild(Child child) {
    child.Beat(this);
  }
}
```

Then the cat can't beat your child:

```
class Cat {
  public void BeatChild(Child child) {
    child.Beat(this); // Does not compile!
  }
}
```

If other people need to be able to beat the child, define an interface they can implement:

```
interface IChildBeater { }
```

Then have them implement it:

```
class Child {
  public bool IsBeaten { get; private set; }

  public void Beat(IChildBeater beater) {
    IsBeaten = true;
  }
}

class Mother : IChildBeater { ... }

class Father : IChildBeater { ... }

class BullyFromDownTheStreet : IChildBeater { ... }
```

Comment: thx. but what if we can't define or change the _Beater_? i.e, the _Child_ code is client code, while the _Beater_ may be a third-party package which implements some functions like serialization and can be replaced by another liberary later?

Comment: In that case there's probably not a lot you can do. If the author of Beater defines the interaction between it and Child you'll probably just have to trust the third parties will do the right thing. It's more of an education and documentation problem than something that can be solved in code.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually achieved by using separate assemblies and the [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx). When you mark the `set` with `internal` classes within the current assembly will have access to it. By using that attribute, you can give specific other assemblies access to it. Remember by using Reflection it will still always be editable.